# PHP login page not working

Tags: php, authentication, syntax-error, login-script

I'm stuck on this thing since last night, so at last I decided to ask you guys about this.

What am I supposed to do to solve this? Are there any errors? Please help; I'm new to PHP.

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect($HOST,$USER,$PASS) Or Die ("Could not connect to the server");
mysql_select_db($DBNAME, $connection )Or Die ("Could not connect to the server");

error_reporting(0);

if ($_POST['Register']);{
  if($_POST['Username'] && $_POST['Password']);
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string(hash("sha512",$_POST['Password']));
  $name ='';
  if($_POST['Name']){
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST[name]));
  }
  $check = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'Username'='$username'"));
  if ($check != '0'){
    die("Uh Oh! That Username has already taken! Try <i>$username" . rand (1,50) . "</i> instead! <a href='register.php'>&larr; Back </a>" );
  }
  if (!ctype_alnum($username)){
    die("Uh hum ! Your username conatins special characters unfortunately they are not permitted ! Only letters and numbers are allowed! <a href='register.php'>&larr; Back </a>");
  }
  if (strlen($username) >20){
    die("Username Cannot contain more than 20 characters <a href='register.php'>&larr; Back </a>");
  }
  $salt = hash("sha512", rand() .rand(). rand());
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users' ('Username','Password','Name','Salt') VALUES('$username','$password','$name','$salt')");
  set_cookie("c_user", hash("sha512",$username),time() + 24 * 60 * 60, "/" );
  set_cookie("c_salt", $salt, $time () + 24 * 60 * 60, "/");
  die ("Congrts ! you are now ready to use Hack With Nick! You are now logged in !");
}

?>

<body style='font-family: sans-serif,verdana;'>
 <div style='width: 80%; padding: 5px 15px 5px ; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; background-color: #fff; color:000 ; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;'>
  <h1>Register</h1>
  <br />
   <form action='' method='post' >
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <b>Username:</b>
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type='text' name='username' style='padding: 4px;' />
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <b>Password:</b>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type='password' name='password' style='padding:4px;' />
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <b>Name:</b>
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type='text' name='name' style='padding:4px;' />
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <input type='submit' name='register' value='Register' />
      <td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Pair down your code! What line causes the error? What is the error?

Comment: You might find this useful to locate PHP errors: [PHP Lint Online](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/phplint-on-line.html)

Comment: Just to begin with: **do not disable error reporting** when debugging; **do not use mysql_* functions, use PDO**; and **do not rely on indexes being set: use array_key_exists** (or `empty()`). Finally, your SQL code contains errors; for example it's `users`, not 'users'.

Comment: In your title you say there is an error.  In the body of your text you ask if there are any errors.  Also, you don't provide any error output.  You need to fix your wording in your title and body so it's not confusing, and if you are receiving an error then provide the output.

Comment: EVERYTHING in this is wrong or horribly broken. No offending, but this is totally unuseable code! Please search for existing scripts and don't build this by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it would be better if you enable the error reporting.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');
```

Secondly, your input names are all lower cased and you have a missing quote in the name field, hence your if statements don't have any braces which makes them useless. Also as  Iserni mentioned above: *Your SQL code contains errors for example it's users, not 'users'* and it's not `$time` if you are trying to use php's own function, it's `time()`.

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])){
  if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
      $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
      $password = mysql_real_escape_string(hash("sha512",$_POST['password']));
      $name ='';
      if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
      }
      $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'Username'='$username'");
      if (mysql_num_rows($check) != 0){
        die("Uh Oh! That Username has already taken! Try <i>$username" . rand (1,50) . "</i> instead! <a href='register.php'>&larr; Back </a>" );
      }
      if (!ctype_alnum($username)){
        die("Uh hum ! Your username conatins special characters unfortunately they are not permitted ! Only letters and numbers are allowed! <a href='register.php'>&larr; Back </a>");
      }
      if (strlen($username) >20){
        die("Username Cannot contain more than 20 characters <a href='register.php'>&larr; Back </a>");
      }
      $salt = hash("sha512", rand() .rand(). rand());
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO users ('Username','Password','Name','Salt') VALUES('$username','$password','$name','$salt')");
      set_cookie("c_user", hash("sha512",$username),time() + 24 * 60 * 60, "/" );
      set_cookie("c_salt", $salt, time() + 24 * 60 * 60, "/");
      die ("Congrts ! you are now ready to use Hack With Nick! You are now logged in !");
    }
}
```